# Error while setting up Replication for Remote docker registry on JFrog Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I am setting up a remote docker registry on Artifactory. (Remote for Dockerhub)

The URL is set to "https://registry-1.docker.io/", after I put in my Dockerhub credentials everything is working fine.

However, as I want to actively caching the remote registry(to eliminate the network glitches during "docker pull" time), I tried to enable the "Replication", when I clicked the Test" button on the Replication setting screen, I am getting error message

> Error testing pull replication config: 
> Unknown host 'https://registry-1.docker.io/`

Can you guys let me know if "Replication" is meant for this use case? If yes, how to set up the "Replication"?

[image: Screenshot here]

Answer (score 0):

Artifactory supports replication of repositories between two Artifactory instances whereas in your case target is an external docker hub.Hence, it is not possible to setup this replication config.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That explains it. Do you know if we want to eliminate the risk of network glitches (during docker pull), is there a way to proactively force Artifactory to cache external docker images?

Comment: I beleive answer is no because it is tedious task to pull such huge data from docker registry. But you can pull required images based on your use case and make a copy of cached artifacts in a local repository and add both remote & local to virtual in order to avoid any glitch while the metadata is expired for cached objects during network outages. You can make use of [remoteBackup](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/54406c38b1c7f91c265ab11cc38aefeb45cbdd4b/storage/remoteBackup) plugin to take backup cached artifacts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not trying to cache the whole "Dockerhub", I am just trying to cache my own private registry. There are only about 5-10 images (springboot Java), not particularly big. Thanks.